# What's the point using 'Mind you' in just one clause?

Tags: idioms, idioms-in-context

To be honest, after reading about 4-5 definitions of this phrase/idiom and some relevant discussions, I still find it opaque.

These sentences I took from [Collin online dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/mind-you_2) uses **Mind you** without a preceding clause:

> *Mind you, we used to get a clip round the ear off them.*
>
> **Max Arthur Lost Voices of the Edwardians**

> *Mind you, I used to find country dancing quite strenuous.*
>
> **The Sun (2011)**

My question, is it like, saying:

> One thing you should know, we used to get a clip round the ear off
> them.
>
> One thing you should know, I used to find country dancing quite
> strenuous.

?

If not, what's the reason using **Mind you** when there's no a preciding clause to contrast?

Comment: Presumably, in the passages those sentences are quoted from there _was_ a previous sentence. Maybe something like "They were very kind to us. Mind you, we used to get a clip round the ear if we did anything wrong."

Comment: As Collins Dictionar points out before the examples you've cited here: *These examples have been **automatically selected***. You'll note that in the ***first*** three examples *(They pay full rates. Mind you, they can afford it. # I got substantial damages. It took two years, mind you. # You need a bit of cold water. Not too cold, mind)*, which I'm sure were ***manually selected***, the "preceding clause to contrast" is always explicitly included. So it's just that "automatic selection" can sometimes produce "misleading" examples as well as "may contain sensitive content" in the disclaimer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking us to explain why "automatically selected" example usages in dictionaries might sometimes be misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could gloss it by "One thing you should know...", but "however..." might do as well.
The example sentences you quote both suggest a contrasting context. Mind you, the dictionary may not have room to include complete context.

I can't find the sources online, so here's some conjured context:

A. Do you have positive memories of your teachers?
B. In general, yes. Mind you, we used to get a clip round the ear off them.

A. I liked to go to dances for fun. Mind you, I used to find country dancing quite strenuous, but I was really relaxed the next day.